# некорректное центрирование на телефоне ( test iPhone , Android )

Tags: html, css, css3

При `line-height: 32px;` - на десктопе не по центру. Понял что проблема в шрифте, но не знаю как это обойти.

```css
.test {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  letter-spacing: -.2px;
  color: #212224;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">5</span>
```

[image: Скриншот с телефона]

Comment: Высота блока `height: 32px;` на кой ему задавать `line-height: 30px;`?

Comment: на той , что 32 не центрует.)

Comment: ))))) аааааааааааа..... Я то думаю.....

Answer (score 0):

Теперь будет всегда по центру, по вертикали и горизонтали, даже, если изменится высота и ширина у родителя:

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  letter-spacing: -.2px;
  color: #212224;
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">5</span>
```

Comment: Нет , уже пробовал этот вариант. А так же добавлять ещё один спан и уже его центрировать. Костылить == padding: 7px; Тоже не работает . Возможно из-за этого шрифта задача не решаема(